# Block all http calls till an observable returns

Tags: javascript, angular, promise, rxjs

I am working on an Angular interceptor. In the interceptor, I need to before I send any non-GET requests, send a GET request to get a a header from the server and set that header on all requests. Is there a way I can do this? below is my pseudo code:

```js
public intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return this.sendRequest(request, next);
}

private sendRequest(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

this.httpClient.get('/my/end/point', { observe: "response" })
.subscribe(res => {
                const header = res.headers.get('SOME_HEADER');
                //set the header on request and send it 
                //first send request
                return this.processRequest(request, next);
            });
// second process request
return this.processRequest(request, next);
}
```

What I am seeing and expecting is that, processing flows through subscriber and then since it is not yet returned, it goes to the second process request statement. Is there a way I can block all subsequent http requests till the observable returns?

Comment: you want to use `.pipe(takeUntil(obs: Observable<boolean>))`

Comment: @mamichels, this looks promising, can you please elaborate? which observable to pass to it. In my code I have only one observable that I am getting http.get so not sure where I place the pipe and takeUntil.

Comment: You might consider the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), which inherently fetches a resorce's headers then body in two separate asynchronous actions .... as controlled by the client.

Comment: @Roamer-1888, Fetch would have the same issue. The problem is not getting the data, the problem is waiting on the data till it is fetched.

Comment: From what I understand of your requirement, and of fetch, it sounds straighforward. Must be something I haven't grasped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how do you want to block requests, by what actions?

that's how the interceptor should look:

```
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return yourObservable.pipe(
      concatMap(someData => next.handle(request)),
    );
  }
```

I created an example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-guscwc), but you have to be more precise about how you want to stop requests and how to start requests

I hope I understood correctly

```
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (request.method === 'GET') {
      return next.handle(request);
    }

    return yourGetRequest.pipe(
      switchMap(response => {
        // add what you need from the response
        const newRequest = request.clone({ setHeaders: { ...response } });

        return next.handle(newRequest);
      }),
    );
  }
```

Comment: What I am trying to do is for any non-GET requests, before the request is sent, send a GET request, get a header from the GET response, add it to the request header and then send it to the backend. I don't want the non-GET requests sent to backend services without this header, hence the 'block'. Thanks for your response.

Comment: I understood, now I will make an example

Comment: Hi Chris. Thanks for the example. Testing it right now. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi Chris, your solution works, thanks for your example. Is it possible to restrict number of GET calls to one per service call? like if I have a POST, HEAD, DELETE requests to '/my/service/' only do one GET when the first non-GET request comes in so that I can store the CSRF header from this first GET response and use it for subsequent calls to the service? I tried storing it in an object on the interceptor but I think there is racing problem when there are concurrent requests. Thanks.

Comment: I'll look at a solution tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

You'll need `concatMap` for this that waits until its inner observable completes:

```
return this.httpClient.get('/my/end/point', { observe: "response" })
  .pipe(
    tap(res => {
      const header = res.headers.get('SOME_HEADER');
      // Save the header somewhere so you can reuse it later ...
    }), // optional
    concatMap(res => this.processRequest(request, next)),
  );
```

However, if you had multiple concurrent request this will make GET request for `'/my/end/point'` for each one of them. A more complicated solution would use an intermediate shared Subject with the header you need. But implementation would really depend on what exact behavior you need.

Comment: I think you can force it to do one GET request using the share() operator, can you please elaborate on having shared object?

Comment: It is still same issue after using concatMap.

Comment: The concatMap block is never executed.

Comment: I don't think this works in this scenario. We don't have two observables. we have only one from the GET operation. This is an http interceptor so we need to get the header we obtain from the GET observable and add it as a header to the request and not to a child or another observable.